# What does Alex’s mom say to her in Spanish at the end?

Tags: wizards-of-waverly-place

What did Alex’s mom say to her in Spanish at the end of *Wizards of Waverly Place the Movie?*

Comment: Te quiero ("I love you") something. Mehita?

Comment: It will be "mi hijita."

Answer (score 2):

She says

> ***"Te quiero, mi hijita"***

which would be "*I love you, my little girl.*" Or more idiomatically in English, perhaps "*I love you, dear.*"